# Facebook iOS SDK: Login fields do not populate

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-sdk-3.1

I recently submitted an iOS app using the Facebook SDK.  I'm using v3.12.  I followed the tutorial for logging in as posted here.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial  My app was rejected because the "login fields do not populate".  I tested when the Facebook app was installed and when it wasn't installed and in both cases I was able to login.  Has anyone else had their app rejected when using the Facebook SDK for this reason, and how do I fix it?  I'll update this question when I get an answer from the iTunes connect review team.

[image: iTunes Connect Resolution Center screenshot]

edit:  I just tried logging into Facebook with a different email address and I wasn't able to do so. The problem was the Facebook app was in development mode. I switched it to live production mode and I was able to login. Maybe that was the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is approved now. The problem was the app was in development mode. I switched it to production.